# Undefined function or variable 'optimoptions' in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I use this from the documentation:

```
options = optimoptions('fminunc','GradObj','on','Hessian','on');
```

and for some reason I get this error:

```
Undefined function 'optimoptions' for input arguments of type 'char'.
```

I am not sure what is the problem. Also when I type optimoptions in Matlab
it says:

```
Undefined function or variable 'optimoptions'.
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you have Optimization Toolbox installed? What is the output of `ver`?

Comment: This is the output from ver: 8.0.0.783 (R2012b)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function `optimoptions` was newly introduced in `MATLAB R2013a`. It might be the case that you are using an older version of `MATLAB`. If so use `optimset` instead of `optimoptions`.

Comment: If I transfer to MATLAB R2013a, will my old code be still valid?

Comment: Where do I find documentation for optimset? It seems only the 2013a documentation is online.

Comment: Well if you are using an older version, it should contain some documentation about optimset.