# Using fgoalattain

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to use Matlab to goal seek a solution and in the process, display the iterations.

I've setup a simple example as follows:

```
cf = [10,20,30,40];
options = optimset('Display', 'iter');
fgoalattain(@(r) sum(cf)/r - 50, 0.1, 0, 1, [], [], [], [], [], [], [], options);
```

Matlab doesn't show the iterations. I can even replace "options" with "asdasdasd" and it doesn't complain. The answer Matlab returns is 6522 when it should really be 2 (sum(10,20,30,40)/r - 50 == 0).

Can anyone please kindly point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: It shows the iterations for me using R2013b (result is `5.000147502666486e+03`). What Matlab `version` are you using? What happens if you use [`optimoptions`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/optimoptions.html) instead as is suggested by the documentation for `fgoalattain`?

Comment: You should use `optimoptions` and mention the solver name as `fgoalattain`. Still that doesn't solve the issue of why you can't get your answer as 2.

Comment: If you write `50-sum(cf)/r`, then MATLAB comes out of `1e7` range of values. That is understandable. When you keep `fun` as `sum(cf)/r - 50`, r will be increased so that `F(x)-weight*gamma<=goal`. `r` can be increased all the way to infinity and it will keep achieving minimum. This is my estimate. I may be wrong too. Also, why do you need to use `fgoalattain` for this kind of example?

Comment: The r that that function should attain is not 2.  Nominally it's infinity, but the optimizer terminates due to the options.TolFun parameter at r = 5e3 before reaching infinity.  Using fsolve would give 2.  Also note that although putting 'asdasdasd' works, you most likely get a warning along the lines that you have entered garbage and that fgoalattain will use the default options instead.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys. My Matlab version is R2011b and doesn't have optimoptions. I've followed this link and used optimset http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16623814/undefined-function-or-variable-optimoptions-in-matlab

Comment: What I'm trying to do is more complicated than that but thought I will use this as a simple example (I guess, just to learn the setup of Matlab). I'm really just trying to replicate the goal seek function in excel.

Comment: I will leave this open for now seeing how I still don't know how to use fgoalattain. But I managed to solve the above using fminsearch, which when passed with the option Display:iter it actually prints the iterations. Strange