# Rosenbrock minimization using MATLAB optimtool

Tags: matlab, optimization

```
 function [y,Gy]=c6fun3(x)
    y=100*(x(2)-x(1)^2)^2+(1-x(1))^2;
    Gy=[-400*(x(2)-x(1)^2)*x(1)-2+2*x(1); 200*x(2)-200*x(1)^2];
```

.

```
ff  = optimset; 
ff.TolX=1e-10; 
ff.TolFun=1e-20; 
%x = fminunc(f,[0;0],ff)

syms x1 x2; 
f=100*(x2-x1^2)^2+(1-x1)^2;
J=jacobian(f,[x1,x2]);

ff.GradObj='on'; 
x = fminunc(@c6fun3,[0;0],ff)
```

This is also generatimg the following,

```
> main_scr

Local minimum possible.

fminunc stopped because the final change in function value relative to 
its initial value is less than the selected value of the function tolerance.

<stopping criteria details>
```

Comment: What MATLAB version are you using? (e.g. R2014b)

Comment: @hbaderts, 7.12.0.635........2011a

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Undefined function or variable 'optimoptions' in Matlab](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16623814/undefined-function-or-variable-optimoptions-in-matlab)

Comment: I thought so. As you can see in the linked question, `optimoptions` was introduced later.

Comment: @hbaderts, optimsets is also not working.

Comment: (just cleaning up here) ... do you still have a question? It looks like your latest edit solves the original problem...

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis, but, it is stuck with local minimum.

Comment: @anonymous so....you want to do global optimization with a local optimization algorithm?